# * in awk (metacharacters)

Tags: awk, regular-expression

Can you explain me how * works?

I have an input:

```
U         8649 275  Asia
Canada    3852 25   North America
China     3705 1032 Asia
USA       3615 237  North America
India     1267 746  -Asia
Mexico    762  78   -North America
France    211  55   Europe
Japan     144  120  Asia
England   94   56   Europe
cim 
B
BB

BBB
```

I tried a command

```
awk '/B*/' countries
```

And the output was:

```
U         8649 275  Asia
Canada    3852 25   North America
China     3705 1032 Asia
USA       3615 237  North America
India     1267 746  -Asia
Mexico    762  78   -North America
France    211  55   Europe
Japan     144  120  Asia
England   94   56   Europe
cim 
B
BB

BBB
```

I expected only the last four lines as an output.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed the "null string" part in the description of `*`, which is present in every line.

In awk, to match *one or more* B's, use `/B+/`

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand, what I missed?

Comment: Maybe it's a wording issue; the "null" string is the empty string -- *anything* matches.

Comment: OK, when I change input to 'AAZkl' there is empty string too? Where?

Comment: The empty string is found *between* every character, and at the start and end of the string.

Answer (score 3):

`B*` matches the empty string.  There would be a match in-between each character on *every* line.

Here's an educational tool for you:

```
awk -v re='B+' '{ gsub(re, "(&)"); print }' file
```

This `awk` program would match the given expression and replace each match with whatever matched, but in parentheses. It's not perfect, but it serves most simple educational purposes.

The equivalent thing with `sed` would be, for some extended regular expression `PATTERN`,

```
sed -E 's/(PATTERN)/(&)/g' file
```

Running the `awk` command on your data with the expression `B+`:

```
$ awk -v re='B+' '{ gsub(re, "(&)"); print }' file
U         8649 275  Asia
Canada    3852 25   North America
China     3705 1032 Asia
USA       3615 237  North America
India     1267 746  -Asia
Mexico    762  78   -North America
France    211  55   Europe
Japan     144  120  Asia
England   94   56   Europe
cim
(B)
(BB)

(BBB)
```

As you can see, only three of the lines at the bottom of the file contains upper-case `B`, so only these are matched.

Another example, using just `B`:

```
$ awk -v re='B' '{ gsub(re, "(&)"); print }' file
U         8649 275  Asia
Canada    3852 25   North America
China     3705 1032 Asia
USA       3615 237  North America
India     1267 746  -Asia
Mexico    762  78   -North America
France    211  55   Europe
Japan     144  120  Asia
England   94   56   Europe
cim
(B)
(B)(B)

(B)(B)(B)
```

Here, each `B` is matched individually.

And finally, your actual expression in the question (my data is not properly tab-delimited), using `B*`:

```
$ awk -v re='B*' '{ gsub(re, "(&)"); print }' file
()U() () () () () () () () () ()8()6()4()9() ()2()7()5() () ()A()s()i()a()
()C()a()n()a()d()a() () () () ()3()8()5()2() ()2()5() () () ()N()o()r()t()h() ()A()m()e()r()i()c()a()
()C()h()i()n()a() () () () () ()3()7()0()5() ()1()0()3()2() ()A()s()i()a()
()U()S()A() () () () () () () ()3()6()1()5() ()2()3()7() () ()N()o()r()t()h() ()A()m()e()r()i()c()a()
()I()n()d()i()a() () () () () ()1()2()6()7() ()7()4()6() () ()-()A()s()i()a()
()M()e()x()i()c()o() () () () ()7()6()2() () ()7()8() () () ()-()N()o()r()t()h() ()A()m()e()r()i()c()a()
()F()r()a()n()c()e() () () () ()2()1()1() () ()5()5() () () ()E()u()r()o()p()e()
()J()a()p()a()n() () () () () ()1()4()4() () ()1()2()0() () ()A()s()i()a()
()E()n()g()l()a()n()d() () () ()9()4() () () ()5()6() () () ()E()u()r()o()p()e()
()c()i()m() ()
(B)
(BB)
()
(BBB)
```

This shows that `B*` matches in-between each character in the whole file, except for between the runs of multiple `B` characters towards the end.

We can also use this to show the difference between `[A-Za-z-]` and `[A-Za-z-]+` (which you asked me about [previously](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89838/discussion-between-lukas-altman-and-kusalananda)):

```
$ awk -v re='[A-Za-z-]' '{ gsub(re, "(&)"); print }' file
(U)         8649 275  (A)(s)(i)(a)
(C)(a)(n)(a)(d)(a)    3852 25   (N)(o)(r)(t)(h) (A)(m)(e)(r)(i)(c)(a)
(C)(h)(i)(n)(a)     3705 1032 (A)(s)(i)(a)
(U)(S)(A)       3615 237  (N)(o)(r)(t)(h) (A)(m)(e)(r)(i)(c)(a)
(I)(n)(d)(i)(a)     1267 746  (-)(A)(s)(i)(a)
(M)(e)(x)(i)(c)(o)    762  78   (-)(N)(o)(r)(t)(h) (A)(m)(e)(r)(i)(c)(a)
(F)(r)(a)(n)(c)(e)    211  55   (E)(u)(r)(o)(p)(e)
(J)(a)(p)(a)(n)     144  120  (A)(s)(i)(a)
(E)(n)(g)(l)(a)(n)(d)   94   56   (E)(u)(r)(o)(p)(e)
(c)(i)(m)
(B)
(B)(B)

(B)(B)(B)
```

```
$ awk -v re='[A-Za-z-]+' '{ gsub(re, "(&)"); print }' file
(U)         8649 275  (Asia)
(Canada)    3852 25   (North) (America)
(China)     3705 1032 (Asia)
(USA)       3615 237  (North) (America)
(India)     1267 746  (-Asia)
(Mexico)    762  78   (-North) (America)
(France)    211  55   (Europe)
(Japan)     144  120  (Asia)
(England)   94   56   (Europe)
(cim)
(B)
(BB)

(BBB)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, so null string is between two characters?

Comment: @LukášAltman Yes. A null string is an empty string, a string containing nothing. A match of the empty string is possible between every character.

Comment: Thus, when I write LL it means charakter L empty string and charakter L?

Comment: @LukášAltman For the purpose of matching a regular expression that could match an empty string, yes.